# Why string.classify is not working as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Using rails 4, `'popup_cta'.classify` results into `PopupCtum`instead of `PopupCta`

I tried `'popup_cta_'.classify` generates the expected result `PopupCta`

Also, when add a resource of `popup_cta` in the routes the rails will create `popup_ctam`  helper

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [classify](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) works under the assumption that you're passing as parameter a table name, which are usually in plural and transform it to singular.
I'm not an native english speaker, so I'm not quite sure what's that specific rule where words in plural that finish with `a`, in their singular form finish with `um`, but what you want to achieve, it can be done with [`camelize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize):

```
'popup_cta'.camelize # => "PopupCta"
```

About your issue with routes, you could override the helper name with [`:as`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.2/routing.html#nested-names).